# Why is running an Azure CLI command in a pipeline super slow?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I am very new to ADO pipelines in Azure. I have a situation where I have the build ID of a pipeline run that created an artifact. I need to download this artifact in a different pipeline. In order to use `DownloadPipelineArtifact@2` you have to provide *both* the `pipeline` an `buildId`.  [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-pipeline-artifact-v2?view=azure-pipelines)

In my case, I only have the `buildId` and figured I could look up the pipeline via an `az` command, like so:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: lookup pipeline ID
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: $(ServicePrincipal)
      scriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        pipelineId=$(az pipelines runs show --id ${{ parameters.buildId }} --query "definition.id")
        echo build ${{ parameters.buildId }} belongs to pipeline $pipelineId
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=pipelineId]$pipelineId"
    env:
      AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
```

This all works as expected, **BUT** when I run that same `az` command from my local machine, it returns in < 1 second... When it runs in my pipeline, it takes closer to **1 minute**.

[image]

what am I doing wrong (if anything) and what could I do to make this command happen faster?

**UPDATE 1**

Based on jessehouwing's answer, I updated my step like so (I'm on a Windows-hosted agent, not self-hosted):

```
parameters:
  buildId: ''

steps:
- bash: |
    pipelineId=$(az pipelines runs show --id $BUILD_ID --query "definition.id")
    echo build $BUILD_ID belongs to pipeline $pipelineId
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=pipelineId]$pipelineId"
  displayName: lookup pipeline ID
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
    BUILD_ID: ${{ parameters.buildId }}
```

And it actually ran **SLOWER**,

[image]

[image]

So, while using bash still got me the data I needed, it didn't speed anything up.

**UPDATE 2**

so, I updated my `lookup-pipeline` step as you suggested, but it had a typo....and the pipeline ID was never returned:

[image]

much to my surprise, the download step **did not fail**.... it actually downloaded the correct artifact.  I tested a redeploy of an older build just to make sure it wasn't grabbing the "latest" build.  Sure enough, from what I can tell....[despite the docs saying otherwise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-pipeline-artifact-v2?view=azure-pipelines#:%7E:text=.%20string.-,Required%20when%20source%20%3D%3D%20specific.,-The%20definition%20ID), the `pipeline` doesn't *appear* to be required when attempting to download an artifact from a pipeline in the same org.  Therefore, I have eliminated the lookup step entirely and the entire pipeline works as expected.

Another tragic case of out of date MS docs

Comment: Just expand the logs to see it does so much more than just your local script. It Checks the version of `az-cli` and all of the extensions, it auths against azure anf then it runs the script and then it logs out again. The task adds quite a bt of overhead. In your case you can probably just run a `bash@2` script step instead of the Azure CLI one, since you're passing in the token of the pipeline anyway.

Comment: You can probably completely forego this step by simply replacing the step with referencing `System.DefinitionId` in a future step. That will contain the Pipeline's definition id. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: "You can probably completely forego this step by simply replacing the step with referencing System.DefinitionId in a future step." Nope.....in the deploy pipeline, I need the definition of the build pipeline so I can download the attached artifact.  That said, I'll try a simpler "bash" script and see if it works any faster

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug in the current hosted runner image which causes `az cli` to discover all of the installed modules and extensions on the first call, because this data is lost in the provisioning process. This enumeration takes around 50s.

Update: A number of pull-requests are making their way to the public runners, the ones in green have already been deployed.

- ✅ actions/runner-images/8410 - Warms up az devops, installs Python's keychain package and run az devops warmup on Windows
- ✅ actions/runner-images/8410 - Redirects all temporary/cache files to a central folder, runs modules during warmup on Windows.
- actions/runner-images/8441 - Redirects all temporary files to a central folder, installs Python's keychain package and runs modules during warmup on Ubuntu.
- azure/azure-cli/27545 - Fixes case-sensitive check against the command index and prevents unwanted index invalidation.
- ✅ actions/runner-images/8388 - Disables Windows Storage Service.
- ✅ actions/runner-images/8431 - Disables Windows Update & Windows Update Medic services

With these changes, first-call performance is now less than ~15s instead of ~60s or more on Windows.

I've [captured all of my findings from the last week looking into this issue in an extensive blog article](https://jessehouwing.net/az-cli-performance-azure-pipelines-and-github-runner/).

Comment: I'll try the bash change out.  I can't use `System.DefinitionId` because that's the value I'm looking to get *from a different pipeline*.

Comment: I tried your suggestion....actually ran slower....updated the original question with results

Comment: will check shortly..... "Funnily enough ubuntu-latest is still much faster than windows." is that *really* that surprising :-)

Comment: see update #2 - I _hate_ working with Azure DevOps

Comment: so, I see things merged....when will this end up in end users agents?

Comment: I just added a step in a pipeline to kick off an AZ command as a bash task and the step ran in 5 seconds!!!!

Comment: You're welcome! If I truly made your life better consider sending me a beer on GitHub sponsors.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to switch to macos-latest and use PowerShell Core